# IM Accounts Pidgin Instant Messaging

Tags: 14.04

Can I just install pidgin instant messaging?  It told me to enable IM accounts and I don't know where to find the settings to do so.

The instructions said to go to **Accounts** -> **Manage accounts**.

Where is this located?

Answer (score 0):

It's located under Settings:

[image: settings]

then

[image: system settings]

If, for some reason you don't have that icon on the side bar, just search `online accounts` in the dash, and it will come right up:

[image: dash]